# ASP.NET MVC IIS 7 - Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"] returns empty string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, iis-7.5

My app has form authentication but I bypass the form when the user is an admin.  I do this by pulling the username with this code:

```
Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
```

Once pulled, I use the name returned to authenticate against LDAP.  This works fine when run inside VS on my local machine.

When I run with IIS this value is blank.  The reason for this is due to having anonymous authentication enabled for my app.  Ref: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306359

As far as I know I require Anonymous Authentication enabled for apps with forms authentication.

Is there anyway I can pull the user that is logged into the PC?

Update: I've come to the conclusion that I can't use Anonymous Authentication.  I get the following error when I only have the Forms Authentication setup though:

```
HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm facing the same frustrating issue :(

Comment: I ended up using Windows Authentication and re-directing to a Form login page for particular users.  I couldn't get to work otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Last answer is Microsoft's solution, but I found the real reason:

### Apparently, ServerVariables have been depreciated for C#

So for C#, you need to do it this way:

```
string login = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

I don't want to **delete** the last answer, because it may work for people running on older versions of C#.

Comment: this is not getting the correct username when project is deployed in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix forms and windows authentication. Have a look at a similar solution here: http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/craig/archive/2004/07/24/1699.aspx

You might not have the described checkbox in the login form, but you could just check the LOGON_USER in the HTTP header.

Comment: I'm doing pretty much exactly what is being done in the link.  I'm getting the 401.2 error though.

Answer (score 0):

The KB article [PRB: Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") Returns Empty String in ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306359) never says where `<authentication mode="Windows" />` goes.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
```

Obviously, I am having issues with this too, or I would not be here.